# How to set span's height to the max height of the spans in the same row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, alignment

Consider the following html code:

```
<span style="display: inline-block;">
<div>Caption - to display at top</div>
<div>Picture - to display at the middle</div>
</span>
<span style="display: inline-block;">
<div>Caption - to display at top</div>
<div>Picture - to display at the middle</div>
</span>
```

When these spans are shown next to each other (2 or 3 in a row), I want that the captions are aligned at the top and pictures are aligned at the center. Pictures may be of different sizes, and captions may occupy multiple lines. E.g. here is what I have currently: http://probqa.com/
[image: Current state - both image and caption are top-aligned]
And here's how I want it to look:
[image: Desired - caption is top-aligned and image is center-aligned]
Is this possible to do just in HTML/CSS? How?

Or do I need some JavaScript for this? What?

Answer (score 0):

To put something in the center, you can use this css trick:

```
.center{
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%; /*move the top left point of block to the center*/
  transform: translate(-50%,0%);
  margin-top:60px;
}
```

Change the margin-top property when you want to change the distance between two images or text.

Comment: This doesn't work: the image just appears at the center of the window this way.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each span box into a `table-cell` so they will have an equal box height, then you can easily align things inside each box using the css `vertical-align: middle` property

```
<span style="display:table-cell">...</span>
<span style="display:table-cell">...</span>
```

Note that you should show border of each box to easily debug them.